# Android TextView with image background added padding on Nexus 4

Tags: android-layout, textview, android-xml, android

I have a TextView showing one line in an app I'm developing.
On other phones (HTC m7, Galaxy note 2) it works fine, but on the Nexus 4 (vr 4.3 & 5.0) the texts gets cut at the bottom, as if there is a large **padding** all around.

Setting the background as a color, or nothing, fixes the padding (on other phones this remains the same) - this is a bad solution.
Setting both padding (including **start/end**) or **includeFontPadding** does nothing.

Any ideas?

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/labelHolder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="46.6dp"
    android:background="#0000"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:minWidth="77dp"
    android:maxWidth="150dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="18.6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:background="@drawable/name_label"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:lines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/opponent_ring_label_text" />
```

Thanks in advance,
Shachar.

Comment: Add your code here it will help you to describe your code in proper way

Comment: There is no actual code, it's just the XML, added